# MobaXterm configuration is not saved

Tags: ssh, mobaxterm

I have MobaXterm free installed version on Windows 10.

When I open the application I add an SSH key in Configuration/SSH. But when I close and then reopen the application, I have to add the SSH key again.

How can I get MobaXterm to save its configuration settings.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like global settings are not saved in the free version. I needed to change the setting in the session and save the session.